# Are there programs for drawing diagrams for systems/devices but not circuits?

Tags: drawing, diagram

I sometimes need to make diagrams(not circuit details) to explain the system(how the devices are interconnected as a big picture):

Here a primitive one in MSPaint:

[image]

Is there a better adhoc program for this purpose?

Comment: Try Libreoffice Draw.  It's free!  https://www.libreoffice.org/

Comment: Or http://draw.io might suffice.

Comment: or "dia" or "visio" etc.

Comment: Dia or inkscape

Comment: https://www.yworks.com/products/yfiles/gallery

Answer (score 1):

I have come to like the [Scheme-It](https://www.digikey.com/schemeit/project/) tool from Digikey, it works pretty well for the task you describe. I have also used Lucid-chart and [draw.io](https://www.draw.io). The Latter interfaces with the google office tools pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

A free and pretty nice vector drawing tool is [GravitDesigner](https://www.designer.io). It can handle all sorts of graphics. You can try it on-line or download it for almost any device including Windows, MacOS, Android, ChromeOS, and Linux.